# Ambiguous Reference error between two namespaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I get this message while trying to run a webservice on the browser. Note that the source code is a windows file and can't be changed for my need.

> Compiler Error Message: CS0104: 'Message' is an ambiguous reference
>   between 'ThreeDSeekUtils.Message' and
>   'System.Web.Services.Description.Message'
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 263:    void WriteSoapMessage(MessageBinding messageBinding,
>   Message message, bool soap12) {
>         objectId = 0;  SoapOperationBinding soapBinding;
>
> Source File:
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx

How can I go about resolving this without removing the namespaces of ThreeDSeekUtils and System.Web.Services from my Webservice? (I need both these in my webservice - Service1.asmx)
This question wasn't answered before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to adjust the signature to specify the explicit namespace of the `Message` class:

```
void WriteSoapMessage(MessageBinding messageBinding, 
    ThreeDSeekUtils.Message message, bool soap12)
```

*or*

```
void WriteSoapMessage(MessageBinding messageBinding, 
    System.Web.Services.Description.Message message, bool soap12)
```

Whichever is appropriate. Another option is to alias your namespaces in the `using` block at the top of the class:

```
using ThreeD = ThreeDSeekUtils;
using ServicesDesc = System.Web.Services.Description;
```

Then you could use the aliases in shorter form:

```
void WriteSoapMessage(MessageBinding messageBinding, 
    ThreeD.Message message, bool soap12)
```

*or*

```
void WriteSoapMessage(MessageBinding messageBinding, 
    ServicesDesc.Message message, bool soap12)
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to write your methods with the full namespace like:

```
void WriteSoapMessage(MessageBinding messageBinding, ThreeDSeekUtils.Message message, bool soap12)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fully qualify the class name when you declare your variable.

Don't do

```
Message msg = new Message();
```

Do:

```
ThreeDSeekUtils.Message msg = new ThreeDSeekUtils.Message();
```